# Fail to scrapyd-deploy

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapyd

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/usr/local/bin/scrapyd-deploy", line 273, in 
    main()
  File "/usr/local/bin/scrapyd-deploy", line 95, in main
    egg, tmpdir = _build_egg()
  File "/usr/local/bin/scrapyd-deploy", line 240, in _build_egg
    retry_on_eintr(check_call, [sys.executable, 'setup.py', 'clean', '-a', 'bdist_egg', '-d', d], stdout=o, stderr=e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/utils/python.py", line 276, in retry_on_eintr
    return function(*args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 540, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/usr/bin/python', 'setup.py', 'clean', '-a', 'bdist_egg', '-d', '/tmp/scrapydeploy-sV4Ws2']' returned non-zero exit status 1

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error and fixed the Setup.py file.
Somehow the installation of the scrapyd-client modified the setup.py file on the project directory and it was causing an error with the scrapy-deploy command.

Please make sure the setup.py file looks something like this: For some reason the "scr" was added before the python command causing an issue.

setup.py:

## Automatically created by: scrapyd-deploy

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name         = 'project',
    version      = '1.0',
    packages     = find_packages(),
    entry_points = {'scrapy': ['settings = <ProjectName>.settings']}
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Facing the same issue, the solution was hastened by reviewing scrapyd's error log. The logs are possibly located in the folder /tmp/scrapydeploy-{six random letters}/. Check out stderr. Mine contained a permissions error: `IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/binary_agilo-1.3.15-py2.7.egg/EGG-INFO/entry_points.txt'`. This happens to be a packaged that was installed system-wide last week, thus leading to `scrapyd-deploy` failing to execute. Removing the package fixes the issue. (Instead, the binary_agilo package is installed in a virtualenv.)